# how to create sorting using hyperlink header text in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

i have a report, when clicked on the header text will automatically sort by **Asc**, when I click on it again it will automatically sort by **desc**. how to make it in crystal report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before doing the below process... First apply the group sort or record sort first from `Report` menu

you need to use `Sort Control` to achieve that.

Sort control is available at `Insert` menu select that and select where you wish to apply sort.

Then draw a box on the header and give it a name. When you preview sort control will be active where you can sort `ascending` and `descending` as required.

Comment: why in the insert menu there is no sort control ? I use crystal report XI release 2. I have also been looking at other menus but not found. do you know where the sort control in   crystal report XI release 2 ?

Comment: I use cr 2008 where I can see the sort control

Comment: is there another way? for example : in my report i use checkbox , when i checked the checkbox it will be sorting by asc when i clicked it again , it will be sorting by desc. what could it be?

Comment: You mean manipulate it by code... I am sorry I have no idea of coding I use crystal reports as a standalone application

Comment: already have you ever use crystal report XI release 2?  I wonder why no sort control in the tab menu .